# How do you have at least 1 of something in a datatype?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm currently creating a table and I have an attribute where it would be of type INT, but it needs to be at least 1.

How do I ensure this?

EDIT: Using MySQL

Comment: Is mysql all you have or is there some other tech involved such as php,java c#?

Comment: In MySQL, check constraint does not work. One thing that you can do is, change your datatype to `unsigned int`. this will ensure values >= 0. But, 0 can still be there. Only solution left now is to use two triggers: `before insert` and `before update`.

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm only using mysql, but it looks like I may need to use triggers.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Ah okay thank you I believe that is what I need

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya How would i go about making a trigger that checks if the value is >0?

Comment: What would you like to do if the value is not > 0,  Throw an error,throw a warning, check and insert 1 or something else? BTW there is an example'UPDATE trigger that checks the new value to be used for updating each row, and modifies the value to be within the range from 0 to 100' which is very similar to what you may want https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not using MySQL.
You could apply a check constraint while creating the table.

```
create table sample(someCol int check(someCol >= 1));
```

This would do if you want the int entry to be greater or equal to 1 always.

Note: check constraint is ignored in MySQL.

If you want to ensure that 1 is entered in the column of the table if while entry, user does not enter something, you can put the default constraint.

```
create table sample(someCol int default 1);
```

Comment: Sorry should have specified, yeah I am using MySQL.